# Join SQL tables where an element is present in a list

Tags: sql, presto

I have a subquery that finds IDs that I'm interested in, the results look like this:

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
| 42|
| 54|
|...|
+---+
```

I then have a larger table that has a column consisting of lists of IDs

```
+------------+
|      id_lst|
+------------+
| [42, 63, 6]|
|  [5, 2, 62]|
|         ...|
+------------+
```

I would like to join these tables where the ID from table 1 is present i the list in table 2. These are both very large tables and I can't seem to find a computationally inexpensive way to join these.

Comment: You could join and the logic would depend on the types, which you didn't show.  Probably the suggested approach is to change the design of the list table to have columns: `(id_list, id_item)`, with a row for each item in the list.  Now we can join on `item.id = list.id_item` and with a usable index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contains` as join clause:

```sql
WITH dataset (value, id_lst) AS (
    VALUES ('a', array [ 1, 2 ]),
        ('b', array [ 4 ]),
        ('c', array [ 1, 5 ])
),
parent(id) as (
    values (1),
        (2),
        (3),
        (4),
        (5)
)

select id, value
from parent p
join dataset on contains(id_lst, p.id)
```

Output:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 4 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 5 | c |

Or use `UNNEST` to expand array into relation and perform "conventional" join:

```sql
select p.id,
    value
from parent p
    join (
        select value,
            id
        from dataset
            CROSS JOIN UNNEST (id_lst) as t(id)
    ) c on p.id = c.id
```

Output:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | a |
| 1 | c |
| 1 | a |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | c |